# Command to know if electricity went down? or to trigger an action when power electricity went out?

Tags: command, hardware, power-management, battery

I have an old laptop where the battery passed away - *because is not possible buy a new or certificated compatible battery, it because the model is about 10 years ago* - therefore when the power electricity goes down the laptop immediately goes down too.

An option is buy a UPS power supply, but if I am out of home there is nobody to shutdown the laptop in peace.

Therefore the purpose is create a kind of daemon running each N time a command one that detects if the electricity went down **or** use the command two that is triggered automatically when the electricity went down.

Is possible accomplish this goal? Mostly for the first scenario?

**Note:** The laptop is a Toshiba Satellite **L845-SP4146KL**

Comment: I'd like to note that 10 year old laptops with some battery capacity remaining might be significantly cheaper than a new ups

Comment: I did do a research on Amazon. There are no batteries for this model. Same case for newegg. Pls if you have a page of recommendation to buy in USA. Pls let me know to notify my uncle.

Comment: I was thinking of a used laptop, not only a battery. I tend to buy used business laptops, as they are usually robust, you still get replacement parts (even new third-party batteries, should the included one not suffice), and still "good". For example,in Germany you can get used leased-and-returned 8GB RAM Thinkpad T430 for <200€ from a recognized store,sometimes even things like an X270 in a similar configuration. I'm sure your averaged "used thinkpads" search result will have similar offers in the US. I don't know your 10-year-old laptop,so,it's hard for me to guess an equivalent device&cost.

Comment: Manuel, don't know whether [this](https://www.backmarket.com/en-us/l/thinkpad/84a212a4-a740-428d-aa37-f0115aad5ab7#backbox_grade=11%20Good&backbox_grade=10%20Excellent&price=0&price=200&sort=prod_us_index_backbox_price_asc_en-us) link works for you, but it's the first used thinkpad store I found on my search engine. I don't know it, but it seems reasonably trustworthy. No guarantees from my side, though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and link - the model was added in the OP. Thank you.

Comment: yeah, that's really really low-end. You can get a better used laptop for the price of a UPS. That's the way I would go. See the link I posted – anything that's not a Chromebook would work for you.

Comment: The laptop was donated by a member of a family - I bought a SSD 1TB and Ram up 16 GB - it works very well, I am very happy with this gift ... but I want have solved the situation about the battery - it seems the best approach is get a UPS as last line of defense

Comment: the RAM and the SSD could be transfered to a different laptop, but your desired solution is of course your business.

Comment: I did an upgrade about hardware to that laptop. The improvement was really notorious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your laptop loses power as soon as the electricity goes, there isn’t anything you can run on the laptop to handle that. However, if you get at least a few seconds, you can detect the loss of power using `udev`, and start shutting down. See [System event on AC adapter insert or battery unplugged?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227918/86440) for details (some experimentation is involved).

Many UPSes are capable of notifying one or more computers when they lose power, leaving time for an orderly shutdown if circumstances warrant it. See [Network UPS Tools](https://networkupstools.org/) for details (these are relevant even if no network is involved).